# Clush scripts input/output redirect

Tags: python, ssh, cluster-computing

Good day,

I am completely new to cluster programming. I need to run a python script on multiple computers, which I figured can be done with "clush". The scripts might however require some input (y/n prompt).

Does clush display outputs of any of the nodes and enable me to write input to them? I must say I don't have tested that because I am not the admin and can't install clush by myself.

Also if there are any other solutions to this, I'd be glad to hear them

Answer (score 0):

clush is just parallel SSH. It means your command is to be run on multiple nodes.

If you need just singe y/n prompt, you can run the clush like this:

```
clush -bw @nodes "echo 'y' | command"
```

If you need more inputs I suggest that you use expect and encapsulate you script/command with it. Then you can run the expect script:

```
clush -bw @nodes script.exp
```

See http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/expect1.html